# Website not appearing on Google search after being indexed

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, google-index

I built a website for people to live stream their studying/working and to find study/work buddies (`salon-live.website`). The website has been indexed by Google Search. However, when I tried to search my website using words in the html title and description meta tag, I cannot find my website after scrolling more than 10 pages. I checked the "crawled page" on Google Search Console and it is exactly what it is supposed to be. At least textually, my website should have a high relevance to the keywords I typed when doing the Google search. I am wondering what might go wrong and what I can do to increase its ranking. Thanks!

Comment: For what it's worth, starting a few weeks ago Google has been unusually slow to show new content from my own website in search (even though it shows as "indexed, can appear in Google Search results" in Search Console). Probably just a coincidence, but it's possible that they're currently having a system-wide issue of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Doing a site:salon-live.website search shows that what Google has currently indexed is sub optimal. Like the title is "React App".

You're latest version of the page is a little better. I'd do a Url Inspection in the Google Search Console and then a Request Indexing. Hopefully that would speed up re-indexing so that Google sees your new title.

meta description has no ranking influence. I think you need to work on your visible content, which is Googles main source on what to rank you for.

Comment: Hi Tony thanks for the reply! Yes I just realized that the crawled page of salon-live.website is not the latest version. However, the crawled pages of salon-live.website/buddies and salon-live.website/livestreaming are indeed the latest version. For example, the description of the buddies page is "Find your study/work buddies." I searched "salon find your study work buddies" but could not see my website after a lot of pages. Also, I am not sure what I should do to make the visible content increase the ranking of the site, as it is just users' profiles.

Comment: In those cases it's down to content. If you don't explain in visible text what you do, then you won't rank for it. And authority. You need to establish yourself so that Google thinks you are important. The best long term thing to do is create the best website in the world and tell people about it.